# Что провоцирует вызов garbage collector в Java

Tags: java, память, jvm, сборщик-мусора

Я знаю, что *Garbage Collector* производит очистку всегда перед тем, как выдается *OutOfMemoryError*, но хотелось бы узнать, в каких ситуациях это происходит еще. Почему, например, в данном случае не производится автоматический сбор мусора после того, как единственная переменная ссылающаяся на *ArrayList* перестает на него ссылаться, и на каждом проходе в последнем цикле выводится один и тот же объем задействованной памяти?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Exp {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
        ArrayList<Integer> al = new ArrayList<>();
        System.out.println(r.totalMemory() - r.freeMemory());

        for (int i = 0; i < 100_000_000; i++)
            al.add(i);
        System.out.println(r.totalMemory() - r.freeMemory());

        al = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.println(r.totalMemory() - r.freeMemory());
            Thread.sleep(60000);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Тут [достаточно информативная статья на Хабре](https://habr.com/ru/post/549176/), сборщик мусора вызывается при превышении определенного процента занятой памяти. Он проходит по всем ссылкам и в зависимости от их типа, освобождает место в куче.
Так же можно "попросить" сборщик мусора сработать, но он **не обязательно** сработает, с помощью команды `System.gc()`